# What does the Ellipsis mean in this Python Function Documentation?

Tags: python, function, argparse

I've been researching for a couple of days what the ellipsis is supposed to mean [in this context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method):

`ArgumentParser.add_argument(name or flags...)`

I understand that Ellipsis is a placeholder, or is used in type hinting for `tuples` or `Callable`s.

I tried two days of research and reading several SO articles on Ellipsis, but none reference this use case.

Comment: Informally '...' means "we're skipping some stuff" or "and so forth".  Python has a formal `Ellipsis` object which `numpy` uses in indexing and display.  But in this documentation it's just trying to give a sense of "one or more flags",  e.g. `add_argument('-f','-f', '--foo', '--foobar', ...)`.  In a parser help and usage '...' indicates multiple items of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the example makes it clear just a [few lines later](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags) in the linked reference:

> The first arguments passed to add_argument() must therefore be either a series of flags, or a simple argument name.
>
> [...]
>
> `parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')`

It means you can add an arbitrary number of arguments, so it acts like varargs of a variadic function in C++. Since it's a Python documentation, they should probably have written `*args` or similar.

Comment: Why couldn't we just write `ArgumentParser.add_argument(*name or *flags)`?

Comment: They could and maybe should have written that, yes.